# How to access Outlook calendar with MacOS Python

Tags: python, macos, outlook, outlook-calendar

I need to make a program that is able to access Outlook calendar events (specifically, the titles). I know there is probably a way to do this with the pywin32 module. But I have MacOS so it's not compatible.

I tried looking up alternatives and the only thing I could find was PyOutlook, which basically allows you to access Outlook email but doesn't seem to do anything with the calendar. I am a beginner to Python so I need someone to point me in the right direction here. Is there a way to access Calendar events in Outlook using Python on MacOS, or am I just royally screwed and that's what I get for not owning a PC? Really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: If PyOutlook was a viable option, you should be able to make an HTTP call to the Microsoft Graph API to get the calendar events you need. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0). Here's a similar question which may also provide some guidance: [Reading Outlook calendar events in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70136687/reading-outlook-calendar-events-in-python)

Comment: The second link you sent helped immensely. Using Azure, I was able to get access to a few of the Microsoft Graph API permissions. It's a slightly annoying workaround but it gets the job done. Thank you!